# How to add values in cells ONLY when other columns contain data from a query result

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Link to example file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dCQSHWjndejkyyw-chJkBjfHgzEGYoRdXmPTNKu7ykg/edit?usp=sharing

The tab "Source data" contains the data to be used in the query on the tab "Query output". The tab "Desired result" shows what I would like the end result to look like.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to have the formula in cell A2 on the tab "Query output" to populate the data in all four of the columns, so that it looks exactly like the "Desired result" tab. I know I can get the same result simply by entering additional formulas in C2 and D2, but this is not the objective, I need the results to come specifically from the single formula in A2.

The information in the "Additional data 1" column should simply repeat the word "Test" for every row that contains data in the first two columns. The information in the "Additional data 2" column should simply repeat the data from cell 'Source data'!A1 for every row that contains data in the first two columns.

Please feel free to edit the example file as it only contains dummy data. If you like, you can copy the tab "Query output" to create your own working formula for illustrative purposes.

EDIT:
I'm thinking along the lines of creating an array that consists of the required data for the columns "Additional data 1" and "Additional data 2" and then combining that array with the array of the query result which provides the first two columns. I've been experimenting with this in various ways, but so far the only result I have achieved is an error on the first cell of the query results. I also have no idea yet how I could make sure that the second array contains an equal amount of rows to the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add static data into query:

```
=QUERY('Source data'!A3:B,"SELECT A,B, 'Test', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL A '', B '', 'Test' '', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' ''")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this example ton include a column with text values in the query result. This example however doesn't use the value in A1 on the first tab and uses a predefined hardcoded text instead. How can I make it work to also grab a value from a specific cell on a specific sheet and repeat that?

Comment: @Rainier answer corrected

Comment: Thanks again! This appears to work like a charm. Can't wait to put it to the test in my far more complex spreadsheet. What an interesting solution too. I didn't know it was possible to interrupt a query string like that.

Comment: It turns out I'm running into one more obstacle. Hope you have an idea for that as well. In my real data file, I require one column in the middle to remain empty. I have edited the example file to now have three columns of additional data. The column "Additional data 1" should still show "Test", the column "Additional data 2" should show just blanks, and the column "Additional data 3" should show the value from 'Source data'!A1. Do you have a trick up your sleeve for that?

Comment: @Rainier Just add new column with space in Select like: ```=QUERY('Source data'!A3:B,"SELECT A,B, 'Test', ' ', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL A '', B '', 'Test' '', ' ' '', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' ''")```

Comment: Ah, I tried that but without putting a space between the single quotes and it didn't work for me then. Your solution with the space does work. Now I've tried to get an actual blank value rather than a space by doing this...

=QUERY('Source data'!A3:B,"SELECT A,B, 'Test', '" & IFERROR(0/0) &"', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL A '', B '', 'Test' '', '" & IFERROR(0/0) &"' '', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' ''")

But this supplies #N/A. Is it possible to get an actual blank value?

Comment: @Rainier Then extend source range in query to include the first blank column and select that, for test data it will be ```=QUERY('Source data'!A3:C,"SELECT A,B, 'Test', C, '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL A '', B '', 'Test' '', C '', '" & 'Source data'!A1 &"' ''")```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @basic for the provided assistance! The insights were a great help to solving my issue. That said, I have muddled along a bit, and I've come up with a slightly different solution which I find better suited as it gives true blank values instead of a column filled with spaces.

First of all, instead of querying directly on the source data, I built an array and queried on that. I used the two existing columns (A and B) from the source data and added a third column to the array which does not exist in the source data. In order to make sure that the third column would consist of blank values, I used the IFERROR formula.

```
=IFERROR(0/0)
```

The formula above returns a blank because dividing by zero forces an error and the IFERROR method returns a blank unless an alternative return value is specified.

In order to be able to use this formula in an array however, it had to be tweaked slightly, because as it is it would only return a single blank cell value instead of a column of blank values. To do this, I used an already existing column from the source data, and then encapsulated it in an ARRAYFORMULA.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR('Source data'!A3:A/0))
```

Using this, the resulting array has the following formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({'Source data'!A3:A,'Source data'!B3:B,IFERROR('Source data'!A3:A/0)})
```

This creates an array consisting of the two original columns A and B from the source data, plus an additional third column filled with blank values. This array can now be queried upon, and using the tricks previously provided by @basic the desired result as specified in the original question can be achieved.

Due to the query now being used upon a user-defined array, the columns in the SELECT statement now have to be referred to as Col1, Col2, Col3, instead of A, B, C. The final formula now looks like this.

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({'Source data'!A3:A,'Source data'!B3:B,IFERROR('Source data'!A3:A/0)}),"SELECT Col1,Col2,'Test',Col3,'"&'Source data'!A1&"' WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL LABEL 'Test' '','"&'Source data'!A1&"' ''")
```

I hope this information may prove of use to someone else as well.